# Image of unit circle in linear mapping

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Show that the set
$$E = \lbrace Ax \in R^2 \, \big| \, \Vert x \Vert =1 \rbrace $$
fits the equation 
$$ 
\left(\frac{v^Tx}{a} \right)^2 + \left( \frac{w^Tx}{b} \right)^2 = 1.
$$

Obviously $a$ and $b$ will be the singular values of $A$, and $v$ and $w$ will be the left singular vectors of $A$, but I have trouble proving this, or finding a proof.

My own attempt follows along the lines of setting $y = Ax \implies x = A^{-1}y$ and trying to show that $\Vert A^{-1}y \Vert^2$ would fit the equation given. What I get is :
$$
\begin{align*}
\Vert A^{-1}y \Vert^2 &= (A^{-1}y)^T(A^{-1}y) \\
& = y^T A^{-T}A^{-1} y\\
& =  y^T (Q^TS^{-1/2} S^{-1/2}Q)y \\
& = \Vert S^{-1/2} Q^T y\Vert^2
\end{align*}
$$
which would be fine if $y$ only were $x$, but since it's not, I am doing something very wrong.